# How do I find all my bus stations?

Tags: simcity-4

I want to upgrade my city's bus network to a subway network.  How do I locate all of my bus stations so I can replace them?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can see them easily: Use the "Traffic" data view under Mayor mode.

In the top left of the view there is a switch between showing traffic by volume and by congestion. Choose by volume and your bus and subway stations will show up in green.

Comment: I don't think stations show up on the traffic data view.  Facilities show up in the power and water views, but not traffic as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Do the same thing -- Choose by volume- then choose bus, than switch back to congestion. next scroll in and scroll through your town. It does not show bus stops when set to volume.